# Scala counting map objects with specific attribute

Tags: scala, scala-collections, counting

I have `referrals: Map[String, Referral]` and am looking for the best way to count how many of those Referral objects have a certain phase attribute.

```
case class Referral(
    name: String,
    phase: String
)
```

I need a count of how many have `phase` equal to "phase1".

I have been able to simply loop on the Map to collect the Referrals with "phase1" and get them into an Iterable, but I have a hunch that's an unecessary extra step but can't wrap my head around how to do this fluidly.

```
val phase1_refs = for (ref <- referrals.values if ref.phase == "phase1") yield ref.name
val phase1_count = phase1_refs.size
```

What is the syntax to get the size of the phase1_refs using the for? I've been playing with filters on the values but keep confusing myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Also would be cool to set up an Enum class to match to different phases (ex. Enum {phase1, phase2, ...} as well, but I am getting ahead of myself.

Comment: Ha/Doh. Is it as simple as wrapping the for in parens and getting the size? `val count = (for (ref <- referrals.values if ref.phase == "phase1") yield ref.name).size'

Comment: yes that works too. But using `count` is probably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
referrals.values.count(_.phase == "phase1")
```